# Problem with Vue.JS to get content-disposition headers when deployed

Tags: vue.js

I'm facing a problem to get an header in axios to get the file name i want to download in vue.js when it was deployed on static web apps on azure but not in Local, in local it work...

Here is the code i use to get the filename in the header.

```
 const headerLine = response.headers["content-disposition"];
 const startFileNameIndex = headerLine.indexOf('"') + 1;
 const endFileNameIndex = headerLine.lastIndexOf('"');
 const filename = headerLine.substring(startFileNameIndex, endFileNameIndex);
```

The console throw me the error that "headerLine is undefinded"... In response headers i've the content-disposition header visible.

I don't understand why it doesn't work online.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check the server side, see this discussion: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/895

Comment: I've found the problem, it's beetween Azure appService integrated CORS and the exposed header I set in the startup class... IfI set the CORS in Azure, It doesn't look at the cors rules defined in code. I use code only now and it work !